# How to timeout a yield statement in KoaJs/NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, koa

I have a statement which gives its result through yield but in some cases it somehow doesn't work and my yields keep waiting infinitely and the only solutionI'm left with is to restart the application. I want to know if there is any way I can set timeout while getting result through yield in KoaJs

```
var x = yield someFunction(par1)
return (x)
```

my problem is that in few rare cases someFunction does not return any value, and I get stuck in a hell of eternal waiting

Comment: There is a module for that :) https://github.com/wejendorp/koa-timeout This one adds global timeout. If you want this logic only for some places check its implementation: it uses `co` and  `Promise.race` under the hood.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko no that lib didn't work. I guess that library sets timeout for http connection and not yield statements

Comment: surely it works. If you need to use this logic outside of koa middlewares use the same approach: race two promises the one that rejects after certain amount of time and the one you got from wrapping generator with `co`

Answer (score 2):

Write a timeout promise maker:

```
yield new Promise(resolve => {
  someFunction(par).then(resolve);
  setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
});
```